# QLException caught: Column count doesn't match value count at row

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Suddenly I am having a problem with my MySQL database. I have in my database the following columns:

```
P_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
Day_hours INT NOT NULL,
Day_minutes INT NOT NULL,
Km_to_address INT NOT NULL,
Time_to_address INT NOT NULL,
Allday_hours INT
PRIMARY KEY(P_id)
```

In My servlet I send the following request:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Workdata VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, Date);
            pst.setString(2, Name);
            pst.setString(3, Address);
            pst.setString(4, Day_hours);
            pst.setString(5, Day_minutes);
            pst.setString(6, Km_to_address);
            pst.setString(7,  Time_to_address);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
```

So the point is that I have my P_id as primary key, which just should count automatically up every time I add some data. As you can see I don't have a setString to Allday_hours. I am using this column to calculate the Day_hours and Day_minutes. I do this with the query:

```
SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) as Allday_hours FROM Workdata
```

The purpose of this is that my girlfriend work different places during a day. Therefore she can put in fx 5 different places, and then Allday_hours calculate how much she has been working during a day. But when I put in my data in the JSP site I get the error:

QLException caught: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I would guess that it has something to do with my Servlet, where I have my setString(1, Date). I have tried to set it to setString(2, date) and the change the others to 3, 4, 5 etc.

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong here?
Best Regards and good day to you all
From Mads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get the error because your table actually has 9 columns but in your query you are only inserting 7 values without put columns which are involved in the insert query so better to specify in the query which column will be used.
Also your column `Allday_hours`i think shouldn't be in the table because since will be created by your selecting query as fictional. Your `P_id` column can be avoided in the insert query because it's an autoincrement column so it will insert its value by itself

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Workdata (date, name, address...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am gonna try it out now. I actually thought about the Allday_hours. But how could I calculate a day with fx 4 jobs. (I have edited my question, so you can see what I mean)

Comment: It works with the:
String sql = "INSERT INTO Workdata (date, name, address...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

:-)

Comment: If the answer was correct you should mark this answer as correct. If you have a new answer after this problem was solved you should ask a new question with your new scenario instead of editing the actual question

Answer (score 0):

Allday_hours should not be defined as a real column in your data model; you return a fictional column with your select query...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried to delete the column Allday_hours in the database, but I still get the same error. Isn't it something to do with the primary key, or?